# Is it possible to change the provider used by the standard jsr-353 api?

Tags: java, jackson, provider, redefine, jsr-353

I am using the JSON JSR-353 api processor (jar javax.json-api-1.0.jar)  to parse JSON files (using the streaming approach) and I added the JAR "javax.json-1.0.4.jar" that contains the default provider "org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl" (without the second jar I had the exception "Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found" when the JsonParser is created "JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(json);")

My question is:

I need to work with the implementation of Jackson, so how can I set it as the Provider of the JSON JSR-353 API?

Answer (score 0):

Use the class`JsonProvider`:

```
public static JsonProvider provider()
```

> Creates a JSON provider object. The provider is loaded using the `ServiceLoader.load(Class)` method. If there are no available service providers, this method returns the default service provider.

```
Returns:
    a JSON provider
```

**References**

- [JsonProvider (JSR 353 (JSON Processing) API 1.0 API](https://json-processing-spec.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/fcs/javadocs/javax/json/spi/JsonProvider.html)
- [Java API for JSON Processing: An Introduction to JSON by Jitendra Kotamraju](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)
- [JsonProvider (Java(TM) EE 7 Specification APIs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/spi/JsonProvider.html)